# Indexing in room prepackaged database not working

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, indexing, android-room

I have a table in a prepackaged database whose index I created using this query

```
CREATE INDEX index_less_equal_to_L ON entries_less_equal_to_L(entry_word);
```

And I specificied in my room entity using this

```
@Entity(tableName = "entries_less_equal_to_L", indices = {@Index("index_less_ equal_to_L"), @Index(value = "entry_word")})
```

But it doesn't work, shows me this
[build error output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQmtp.png

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to create 2 indicies, 1 for each @Index.

The first will be named **index_less_ equal_to_L** but have no columns (hence the error message).

The second will be created (successfully) with a generated name and be on the **entry_word** column. The name of the index will be as per :-

> If not set, Room will set it to the list of columns joined by '*' and prefixed by "index*${tableName}". So if you have a table with name "Foo" and with an index of {"bar", "baz"}, generated index name will be "index_Foo_bar_baz".

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room

So you need to combine the two into a single index.

You could use either (note the space between `_` and `equal_to_L` removed as I assume that this is a typing error)

```
indices = {@Index(name = "index_less_equal_to_L",value = "entry_word")}
```

or

```
indices = {Index(name ="index_less_equal_to_L",value = {"entry_word"})}
```

The latter being the more flexible as it allows for composite indicies (multiple columns).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!